# Conditional Linebreak for back references

Tags: bibliographies, line-breaking

In my bibliography I use back references. Now, I would like them to appear flush right in the last line of my reference. This can be done easily with an `\hfill`. However, if the back reference becomes to long, it spills into the next line. I prevent this by putting an `\mbox`around the back references. But now, when the whole back reference is put into a new line it is either no longer flush right, or the content of the previous line is streched to fill the whole line.

What I would like to obtain is a flush right back reference, either in the last line of the normal reference if there is enough space, otherwise in the following line. In the latter case, I would like there to be an actual line break, so that the last line of the reference is not needlessly stretched. Any ideas how I can achieve this?

EDIT:

Here is a small example to show what I try to prevent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{backref}

\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \mbox{[some slightly longer text]}%
  \begingroup % keep changes to \parfillskip local
    \parfillskip=0pt %
    \par
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\cite{foo}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{foo} short bibliography entry to fill almost one entire line

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Wen you compile the file, you can see that the actual bibliography line is stretched over the whole page. In this case (the backreference being in a new line), I would like the bibliography entry to not stretch to final line, as in the following example. Though, this example has the problem, that it always uses a new line for the back reference.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{backref}

\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
  \\\hspace*{\fill}\mbox{[some slightly longer text]}%
}

\begin{document}
\cite{foo}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{foo} short bibliography entry to fill almost one entire line

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

EDIT 2:

Further example showing a small bug in the solution kindly provided by Heiko Oberdiek. In the first reference there is a line break before the back reference whereas in the second reference of the same length there is none, which is desired output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{backref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
  \hspace{0.1em plus 1fill}\penalty0 %
  \hspace*{\fill}%
  [no cite]%
  \begingroup
    \parfillskip=0pt %
    \par
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\cite{bt-ilo-97,ccj-udg-90}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[BT97]{bt-ilo-97}
Dimitris Bertsimas and John~N. Tsitsiklis.
\newblock {\em {Introduction to Linear Optimization}}.
\newblock Athena Scientific, first edition, 1997.

\bibitem[CCJ90]{ccj-udg-90}
Brent~N. Clark, Charles~J. Colbourn, and David~S. Johnson.
\newblock {Unit disk graphs}.
\newblock {\em Discrete Mathematics}, 86(1--3):165--177.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have plenty of spurious spaces (the end of lines); I don't know why you're using `\,`. Please, try making a minimal example.

Comment: I added a small example, using Heiko's (unfortunately wrong) answer from below as a basis.

Comment: @shiin: The answer should now work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end of a paragraph TeX removes white space via `\unskip` (usually a space by the last line end) and adds `\parfillskip`, usually `0.0pt plus 1fil`, that fills the last line if necessary. Because you do not want to fill the last line, the following example sets `\parfillskip` to `0pt`. I have replaced `\hfill` by two `\hspace`:

- The first `\hspace{2em plus 1fill}` ensures some space between the bibliography entry and the back references (2em) and fills the line if necessary. At the beginning of a new line, this space is discarded automatically.
- `\penalty0` allows a line break if necessary.
- `\hspace*{\fill}` does not vanish at the begin of a new line and fills the the line until the back references start.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{backref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{%
  \hspace{2em plus 1fill}\penalty500 %
  \hspace*{\fill}%
  \lipsum*[2]%
  \begingroup
    \parfillskip=0pt %
    \par
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}
\cite{foo1,foo2}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{foo1} Foo.

\bibitem{foo2} Foo\hbox to 62mm{\dotfill}Bar.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. Could you please explain, how this worked? EDIT: I just saw, that it didn't work all the time. I try to produce a short example.

Comment: actually after having (correctly) copied your example, I see that it doesn't produce what I wanted. I add a modified version of your solution to my initial question to show the probem.

Comment: Thank you for the updated solution, and the good explanation. By now, it works almost everywhere. Though, there are some instances in which a new line is started for the back reference for no apparant reason. I update my original question again with two wntries taken from my bibliography.

Comment: @shiin: A higher penalty value should help.